# Google Process Location Accessing location for whom?

Tags: location-services

I am seeing google.process.location is always running in my phone and whenever I tried to google it, all the posts are related on how to fix an error in this not what I want to know.

Is it the process responsible for giving Google Maps location data or generally serving the location requests in Android ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That process is used for all Google apps — Maps, Chrome, Google+, etc.  It does not provide location info for independent apps like MapQuest.